# How do I add timing event to an event listener

Tags: javascript

I need to delay this by 3 seconds...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var x = VarPagesInChapter.getValue();
var y = Var_visitedPageCount.getValue();
var progress = Math.round(y/x*100);
document.getElementById('pct').innerHTML = progress+'%';
document.getElementById('radial').classList.add('p'+progress);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `setTimeout()` function:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log( "Loaded at " + performance.now() );
  setTimeout(function() {
    //Your code
    console.log( "I'm ready at " + performance.now() );
  }, 3000); // 3000 milliseconds = 3 sec

});
```

Comment: Wow thank you. I'm trying to beat the learning curve on javascript. I've looked at lots of examples of setTimeout but everything looks so simple compared to practical use cases. In this case I just couldn't figure out how to refer to the function and I've never seen console.log. I guess I have to read more.

Comment: @Andraco console.log is just for demo, to show the 3 sec delay) You can add anywhere `setTimeout(function(){  // any code; }, time);`